# How do I load JSON response array items one by one as I scroll down in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, pagination, gson, retrofit

I'm currently using Retrofit and GSON to retrieve data from my API, and it seems that the data from the array is retrieved at all at once. This shouldn't be a problem if there are only a few items, but it may slow down when retrieving very large data. This is currently what my RecyclerView adapter looks like:

```
public class CuratedSectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static int VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    private List<Object> itemList;

    public CuratedSectionAdapter(List<Object> itemList) { this.itemList = itemList; }

    private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;
        CuratedSectionNestedAdapter nestedAdapter;
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

        ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_nested);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        }
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewHeader;
        Typeface montserratMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf");

        HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textViewHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_header);
            textViewHeader.setTypeface(montserratMedium);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
            HeaderViewHolder viewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
            CuratedSectionHeader header = (CuratedSectionHeader) itemList.get(position);

            viewHolder.textViewHeader.setText(header.getHeaderName());
        } else {
            ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            List<CuratedSectionItem> items = (List<CuratedSectionItem>) itemList.get(position);

            if (viewHolder.nestedAdapter != null) {
                viewHolder.nestedAdapter.setItems(items);
            } else {
                viewHolder.nestedAdapter = new CuratedSectionNestedAdapter(items);
                viewHolder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(viewHolder.layoutManager);
                viewHolder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder.nestedAdapter);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
            return new HeaderViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.main_explore_header_row, parent, false));
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            return new ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.main_explore_row, parent, false));
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Adapter " + viewType + "not found");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position) instanceof CuratedSectionHeader ?
                VIEW_TYPE_HEADER : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}
```

This is how the data is retrieved from the API in my activity:

```
private class LoadSections implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("user_session", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String sessionKey = prefs.getString("session_key", null);

        Call<JsonArray> call;
        call = TravelersApi.endpoint().getCuratedSections(sessionKey);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {
                if(response.code() != 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot load page as of the moment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                JsonArray rawSections = response.body();
                if(rawSections.size() == 0) {
                    //TODO: show placeholder
                    return;
                }
                ArrayList<CuratedSection> sections = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 0; i < rawSections.size(); i++) {
                    JsonObject jSection = rawSections.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    final CuratedSection section = new CuratedSection();
                    section.id = jSection.get("id").getAsString();
                    section.header = jSection.get("section_header").getAsString();
                    section.topicCount = jSection.get("topic_count").getAsInt();
                    section.isShown = jSection.get("is_shown").getAsBoolean();
                    section.stories = new ArrayList<>();

                    sections.add(section);
                }
                curated.setSections(sections);
                curated.loadStories(sessionKey);

                spinner.clearAnimation();
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ERROR!", t.toString());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've been following [this](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-recyclerview-tutorial-api-retrofit-gson/) tutorial to implement pagination/infinite scrolling in my RecyclerView, but the structure and implementation of the adapter and even the models in the tutorial involves scrapping and modifying a huge chunk of my app's current architecture. Is there a nifty or "hacky" way of achieving what I want without building my RecyclerView adapter and activity from the ground up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i create `interface onbottom` and check if the `recyclerview` is on bottom then load more data.
means `count` will `post` into the `API`
first it loaded 1st page data means `count=1`
then when will reach `onbottom` call function again with `count++` to load second page `data`

in my API, page numbers is received as `POST REQUEST` so count is my page numbers. ;)

interface:

```
public interface OnBottomReachedListener {
    void onBottomReached(int position);

}
```

adapter:

```
    OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener;
 public void setOnBottomReachedListener(OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener){

        this.onBottomReachedListener = onBottomReachedListener;
    }
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       final PropertyInfo propertyInfo = propertyInfoList.get(position);

        if (position == propertyInfoList.size() - 1  ){

            onBottomReachedListener.onBottomReached(position);

        }
}
```

Activity:

```
adapter.setOnBottomReachedListener(new OnBottomReachedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBottomReached(int position) {
                count++;
                prepareData(count); //its my logic.. you can do your own logic 



            }
        });
```

Comment: About that `onBindViewHolder` method, how would it affect the code inside my own implementation of `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: it will just check the arraylist whether it reaches bottom or not.

Comment: So it should work perfectly fine if I simply insert that snippet of code inside my `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: why not!
it will check the bottom of your recyclerview.
in adapter.seronbottomreachedlistener you can load more data according to your program.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a a 3'rd party lib that manages that for you. Check out these links:

https://github.com/pwittchen/InfiniteScroll

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView